# Calculating mean with group by based on another column in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, fields-attributes, grouping, mean

I have daily temperature data for several cities from January to December.
I'd like to calculate the average temperature per month for each city in a new column.

I have a column `"city"`, `"day"`, `"month"` and `"temperature"`.
I've tried to do the following in the field calculator, but the result gives the same average temperature for all cities.

```
case
    when "CITY" = 'LONDON' then mean("TEMP", group_by:="MONTH")
    else ''
        end  
|| 
case
    when "CITY" = 'PARIS' then mean("TEMP", group_by:="MONTH")
    else ''
        end
```

Also, I imagine it's possible to do this without having to call the name of each city. This would be great, as there are hundreds of them. How can I modify this code to get the desired result?

I am using QGIS 3.30.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following expression:

```
mean(expression:="temp", group_by:="month" || "city")
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression:

```
array_mean (array_agg (temperature, group_by:=city || month))
```